# Regular Expression that would include control characters

Tags: java, regex

I have a Java process that uses different regular expressions based on which file type I'm processing.  It determines whether the record being read should be kept or not.

I have one file type that I want to include everything.  So, I created its regular expression to:

```
.*
```

This normally works, but I just ran into a problem where a record contained an embedded **line separator** (\u2028) character which cased the regex match to fail (resulting in the record not being kept).

Can anyone recommend a regex pattern that would accept any and all characters?

Comment: Use `(?s).*`....

Comment: Use `[^]*`... ?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts That causes `PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 3`

Comment: @Andreas oh, I wasn't sure if it would work, it was just a guess. I'm used to JavaScript flavor of regexes.

Comment: Wiktor's suggestion worked.  Thanks!